# MVVM Databinding a list

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and I have been trying to use the MVVM pattern.
I am trying to bind 2 properties of a class to a ComboBox and a TextBox.

The ComboBox works fine and I have 2 items in there, but I am unsure how to bind the TextBox to the selected items 'Details' property. So when the ComboBox selected item is changed the TextBox will update also.

Any help would be appreciated.

MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scenarios}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="95" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,412,287" />

    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="119,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Details}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainView.xaml.vb

```
Class MainWindow 
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.DataContext = New MainViewModel()
End Sub
End Class
```

MainViewModel.vb

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class MainViewModel
Public Property Scenarios As ObservableCollection(Of Scenario)

Sub New()
    Dim scenarioList As New List(Of Scenario)

    Dim scenario1 As New Scenario
    scenario1.Name = "Test1"
    scenario1.Details = "Test scenario 1"
    scenarioList.Add(scenario1)

    Dim scenario2 As New Scenario
    scenario2.Name = "Test2"
    scenario2.Details = "Test scenario 2"
    scenarioList.Add(scenario2)

    Scenarios = New ObservableCollection(Of Scenario)(scenarioList)
End Sub
End Class
```

Scenario.vb

```
Public Class Scenario
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Details As String

End Class
```

Comment: Put name on your combobox like x:Name = "MyCombo", then on the Textbox, you put  Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyCombo}"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give Name to Combo and bind to like below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Scenarios}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="95" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,412,287" />

<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="119,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Details, ElementName=myCombo}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```